# Elementary proof that $\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X) \geq 0$

Tags: probability

> I would like to prove that $\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X) \geq 0$ if $Y \geq 0$
> but am not sure I can make a clean proof.

My attempt:

For discrete random variables, $\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X = x )= \sum_{y \in Y} y P(Y=y \mid X=x)$.  We know from the assumption that $y \geq 0$ and we also know that  $P(Y=y \mid X=x) \geq 0$ therefore $\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X = x ) \geq 0$.

If  $\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X = x ) \geq 0$ for all $x$ then $\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X) \geq 0$.

Is this proof correct and as elegant as it could be?

Comment: Is your conditional expectation defined by $\mathbb{E}(Y|X) = \mathbb{E}(Y|\sigma(X))$?  If so, there's no reason to consider a discrete case.  Rather, you can just consider $\{\mathbb{E}(Y|X) \leq -\varepsilon\} \in \sigma(X)$ for arbitrary $\varepsilon >0$

Comment: @BrianMoehring. What does $\sigma(X)$ mean?  Normally that would be the standard deviation but you don’t seem to mean that.

Comment: @BrianMoehring The sigma algebra generated by X?

Comment: Yes, I meant the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$.  (Not truly relevant, but I prefer $\sigma_X$ for the standard deviation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose not.  Then there is some $x < 0$ such that $A_x = \{\mathbb{E}(Y|X) \leq x\}$ has $\mathbb{P}(A_x) > 0$.

Also, since $A_x \in \sigma(X),$ $$0 \leq \mathbb{E}(Y\mathbb{1}_{A_x}) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y|X)\mathbb{1}_{A_x}) \leq \mathbb{E}(x\mathbb{1}_{A_x}) = x\mathbb{P}(A_x) < 0$$

Comment: I think the must be a more elementary proof of this, surely?

Comment: @Anush For me, this is just combining the definition of conditional expectation, the continuity of $\mathbb{P}$, and the property $$X \leq Y \implies \mathbb{E}X \leq \mathbb{E}Y.$$ I don't know how to find a more elementary proof (under some definition of "elementary") but I'd welcome any alternative.